# "Goldbach's other conjecture" and Project Euler - writing 1 as a sum of a prime and twice a square

Tags: prime-numbers, project-euler, conjectures

From Problem 46 of [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=46) :

> > It was proposed by Christian Goldbach that every odd composite number can be written as the sum of a prime and twice a square.
> >
> > $$9 = 7 + 2 \cdot 1^2$$
> >
> > $$15 = 7 + 2 \cdot 2^2$$
> >
> > $$21 = 3 + 2 \cdot 3^2$$
> >
> > $$25 = 7 + 2 \cdot 3^2$$
> >
> > $$27 = 19 + 2 \cdot 2^2$$
> >
> > $$33 = 31 + 2 \cdot 1^2$$
> >
> > It turns out that the conjecture was false.
> >
> > What is the smallest odd composite that cannot be written as the sum of a prime and twice a square?

As soon as I read this problem, I've immediately fought that the smallest odd number 1 was not on the list of examples. Then I've thought that 1 can be the answer. The only way that I could write 1 close to the problem $1=1+2 \cdot 0^2$, Which is of course false. I've also tried to give 1 as answer, but the site didn't accepted. So how can we write 1 as a sum of a prime and twice a square?

Comment: From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number): "The number one is a unit; it is neither prime nor composite"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take primes to be positive, it cannot be done.  This is because primes are greater than $1$, and twice a square number is positive.

This is not contradictory to the problem though, because $1$ is not composite.

If we allow primes to be negative (considering prime elements in the ring of integers), we can write $1=-7+2\cdot2^2$.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see the word composite.

Answer (score 2):

$1$ is not the product of two smaller positive integers. So it isn't composite, and the conjecture doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

1 is a unit number (with multiplicative inverse in the integers), not a composite number. Also, the conjecture is for odd composite numbers which begins from 9.